# Call C# method from javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to call the c# method from javascript. I need the method to be called only when the javascript button is clicked i.e (btnclick()). But Login method gets executed before the onclick of button.

aspx file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function  btnclick()
    {
    <%=Login() %>;     //calling the c# method
    };
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $(".username").focus(function () {
            $(".user-icon").css("left", "-48px");
        });
    </script>
    <body>
    //contains other elements like username and password text boxes
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" onclick="btnclick()"/>
    </body>
```

aspx.cs file

The following c# method have to be called from javascript

```
 protected void Login()
{
//contains method for authentication
}
```

Is there any other way to call c# method from javascript.

Comment: You can't call a C# method from JavaScript.  The two pieces of code are running on different contexts, at different times, on different computers.  What you *can* do is make an AJAX request from JavaScript to a server-side resource (MVC action, ASHX handler, ASPX page, etc.) which calls the function and renders some result in the response.  There are multiple ways to do that, but all of which involve a request/response of some kind. (The reason it's being executed before the button click is because you're executing it when the page renders.)

Comment: But I have given it inside btnclick() event ..why is it executed when page renders...also if I remove  <%=Login() %>; and put an alert over there its executed only on button click @David

Comment: No you haven't.  You need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side code.  All of the server-side code will execute when the page is being rendered, and the resulting page is sent to the client.  From the server's perspective, there's no click event in this code.  All of the client-side code is just one big string as far as the server is concerned.  And from the client's perspective, there's nothing in that click function.  The server-side code already executed by the time the page renders on the client.

Comment: `"also if I remove <%=Login() %>; and put an alert over..."` - That's because `alert()` is client-side code, not server-side.  It behaves differently because it *is* different.

Answer (score 1):

Your question exposes your lack of knowledge about how websites work. You simply cannot execute C# function form javascript code like:

```
function  btnclick()
{
<%=Login() %>;     //calling the c# method
};
```

because javascript is running in the browser and the C# on the server.
The reason that your C# Login method was called is that your button is configured to submit the form and the form I suppose is pointing to your server.

Comment: I tried the web method also but for it the c# method have to be static.How else to call the c# method from JavaScript @Rafal

Comment: From your question I gathered that it was called. If you want to explicitly write a js code that calls your method you would need to execute either a postback on your address by setting window.location to appropriate address (MVC? localhost/YourApp/YourController/Login) or execute ajax call eg. using jquery $.get("address",callbackFunction)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an api controller and putting the method in that? I really like using ProxyApi (it's as simple as adding a NuGet) and it generates clean javascript proxies for you. You'll get it up and running in just a few minutes:

- Add an ApiController and add the Login method.
- Add ProxyApi through NuGet and reference it in javascript: [script src="~/api/proxies"][/script]
- Call your C# method in javascript like this:

  $.proxies.myapi.login(some params).done( function(data) {
      // done!
  });

see: https://github.com/stevegreatrex/ProxyApi

Answer (score -1):

You can define c# method as webmethod.

Try It:

```
[WebMethod]
protected void Login()
{
   //contains method for authentication
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Nikunj B. Balar I tried the webmethod also but for webmethod my method have to be static...

Comment: @Ram: 1) Why does your method need to be static?  (Hint: I bet it doesn't.)  2) You can create a WebMethod which in turn *calls* your static method.  `Login` itself doesn't need to be the WebMethod.

Comment: Generally [WebMethod] used in webservices. A Method must be static when we can define method as "WebMethod".

Comment: only static methods can be used in webservice @David when I use [WebMethod]
protected void Login()
 I get page methods as undefined..@ Nikunj B. Balar

Comment: @Ram: Then make the WebMethod static and call `Login` from it.  The overall point remains the same.  You need some kind of endpoint listening for client requests.  You'd send a request to that endpoint from JavaScript code and receive its response.  That server-side endpoint would execute whatever server-side logic you're trying to invoke.  That's all even assuming that AJAX is the right logic flow for this, which we can't know from what's in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function jsFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('<%=lbSubmit.ClientID%>').click();
}
</script>





<asp:LinkButton  ID="lbSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update Files" 
onclick="cshapbottun_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>



C# code
protected void cshapbottun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//    DoSomething;
}
```